# Can we use the HIV antibody test to detect HIV in newborns?

Tags: antibody, hiv

Adults and elder children can use HIV rapid test to test HIV infection. Can we use the HIV antibody test to detect HIV in newborns too?

Comment: It is a prerequisite here on Biology.se to do some research yourself and not only dump in one sentence questions. Additionally your question is rather broad. So please edit your question and add the information you found yourself and ask about what's unclear.

Comment: The question itself holds potential, please elaborate to avoid closure.

Comment: I found the question fine the way it is. This is how you chase away new members. It's also a prerequisite to assume the question hasn't been answered somewhere else and write an answer here for posterity rather than linking to a uniform resource location that may or may not exist in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The rapid screen usually tests the oral mucosa by swabing the inside of the cheek and checking for the presence of anti-HIV envelope antibodies. Although the precise target of these antibodies seems to be kept propriatary, my guess would be the detection of either p24 antibodies or envelope antibodies that bind the V3 region.

Regardless, the point is they test for the presence of antibodies, which a child does not start making until they are born. [See this post for a great explanation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/at-what-age-do-babies-begin-to-synthesize-their-own-antibodies)

Since a child has mostly maternal antibodies, the presence of anti-HIV antibodies would only mean that the mother has started producing antibodies to HIV ([Seroconversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seroconversion)). This means that although the child has been exposed, they may themselves not be infected.

The mucosa, particularly in the oral region has a very low titer of anti-HIV antibodies, so I think this test would probably be best to direct the physician to conduct additional tests that are more indicative of HIV infection like [p24 western blot](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/00001431.htm).